# Clementine stopped playing music

Tags: kde, pulseaudio, alsa, gstreamer, clementine

I'm using Kubuntu 11.10. Clementine worked great until I had my laptop lag for, most likely, some Flash Player error. I had to manually kill Firefox and Clementine, but upon restart, Clementine does not play any sound anymore. Terminal output doesn't show any error, and the track seemingly is playing, as the "seconds tick" and I receive regular track notifications. The Clementine volume bar shows and responds in the sound menu. Rhythmbox plays files regularly and so do VLC and Flash. I already tried deleting the `gstreamer` folder to force a regeneration but to no avail. I'm at a loss, any help appreciated!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!